# Attempted to assign to readonly property with react-native-dialogflow - Error

Tags: android, react-native, dialogflow-es

We are facing attached issue after adding [react-native-dialogflow library](https://github.com/innFactory/react-native-dialogflow) to our existing project. please guide us if anyone can.

Please find code at this URL - 
[Code Url](https://github.com/innFactory/react-native-dialogflow/issues/23)

Below is the Screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new project and add libraries one by one. After adding each library run project and find the problem. Also see the updated or removed file count after installing, if a new library update or delete existing files, keep track of them. Prefer to use "npm" command instead of "yarn".

For me it was just a problem of "yarn" install command, I used "npm" and its solved.

Answer (score 0):

I used  "react-native": "0.44.0" it's works for me..